# Stopping child entity to update in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am running into problem as my maps are updating child entity  which is actually a view in database here is part of parent map

```
  HasManyToMany(x => x.Child).Cascade.None()
                    .Table("ParentToChild").Inverse();
```

and my child map is like this

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Parents).Cascade.All()
               .Table("ParentToChild");
```

But some how every time i tries to add child object in to parent like parent.Childern.add(child) is gives an error "view can't be updated" which is very true but i havent chnaged anything and i dont want to save or insert child entity as this is a view.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to update a database view instead of a table. Check if the child is a view in your database. If it is, the view can't be updated.

Comment: its a view i know but i need to stop nhibernate from updating it.

Comment: So you want to fetch the data, but you do not want to update? Have you tried specifying that entity is readonly?

Answer (score 0):

Add ReadOnly(); to the map of that entity.